# problem with react slick: import { baseUrl } from "./config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

After having imported everything and installed, I copy and paste any carousel of the code offered by the page, managing to work with the exception of this, the main problem being "baseUr"After having imported everything and installed, I copy and paste any carousel of the code offered by the page, managing to work with the exception of this, the main problem being the "baseUrl"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { baseUrl } from "./config";

export default class CenterMode extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      customPaging: function(i) {
        return (
          <a>
            <img src={`${baseUrl}/abstract0${i + 1}.jpg`} />
          </a>
        );
      },
      dots: true,
      dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Custom Paging</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "/abstract01.jpg"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "/abstract02.jpg"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "/abstract03.jpg"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "/abstract04.jpg"} />
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNriy.png)

Comment: Hi Argus, please share your code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: sorry, it's my first time. Ready.

Comment: config.js is located in the Components directory?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create **at the root of your project** a config.js file like this:

**config.js**

```
export const baseUrl = window.location.origin + '/img';
// 'img' is the images folder in 'public' (project_name/public/img/)
```

**In your slider component**

```
import { baseUrl } from '../config';
// '../config' instead of './config'
```

**Demo:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fcawsf?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCarousel.js)

Comment: friend, thank you really, I have not known what to do for two days. If possible I would hug you